# What brought these couples together?

Tags: wordplay, pattern

Sometimes it's difficult for outsiders to understand what brings a couple together.

What brings each of these couples together?

```
ENTER    INPUT

ROTOR    MOVES

TIGER    STATS

TARGET   DENIER

LITER    SAVER

CIGAR    STAMP

STOPS    RECAP

DETER    CIDER

NORSE    SITED

SENILE   MARTS

STUNS    AORTA

TURBO    EVICTS

CIRCLE   TENON

SNIPS    RETCH

FACTS    TREAT

ABETS    STOMA
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you take the two words,

> reverse them, and then interleave them in some way, you can form a new word.
>
> ```
> ENTER    input     tuRpEnTiNE
> ROTOR    moves     seRvomOTOR
> TIGER    stats     stRatEGIsT
> TARGET   denier    reinTEGRATed
> LITER    saver     RETrIevaLs
> CIGAR    stamp     pRAGmatICs
> STOPS    recap     SpacePOrTS
> DETER    cider     rediREcTED
> NORSE    sited     dESeRtiONs
> SENILE   marts     strEamLINES
> STUNS    aorta     aStroNaUTS
> TURBO    evicts    OBstRUcTive
> CIRCLE   tenon     nonELeCtRIC
> SNIPS    retch     SPhINcterS 
> FACTS    treat     StaTeCrAFt
> ABETS    stoma     STEamBoAts
> ```